# Deploy a Spring app (JAR) for browser

Tags: angularjs, spring, maven, jakarta-ee, deployment

I have no knowledge about deployment, production server, web server, etc. But I have a web application and my boss wants to deploy it in order to access it by web browser.

So, my application was generated by Spring Initializr.

It's using Spring (Boot, Security, Web, Data JPA), with web service REST (@RestController), HTML templates and AngularJS.

With `mvn clean package`, I generated a JAR file of this application. It is working on my desk. But, how can I deploy it?

I believe that my company has an OVH hosting. Can I install JBOSS or Tomcat on it, and upload my JAR on OVH?

Comment: You can deploy it with Pivotal cloudfoundry. I would recommend you to read Spring Boot in action. The book has a chapter expaining how to deploy on Heroku, Pivotal Cloudfoundry ect ...

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your application on Tomcat but you need to have a war instead of a jar to run it on an existing application server.

You can read the following documentation to create the war : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Once done, you just have to upload it on the server in the webapps directory of your tomcat server.

Comment: Otherwise, you can use your jar to run it on the server if it contains an embedded server : https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#embedded-web-server-deployment